# Django: Login a user after a webhook event

Tags: python, django, authentication

i am making an ecommerce app giving users session based cart and allowing then to checkout and enter their email(required) there, where when stripe webhook ping about that checkout session i create that user based on his email or get them from database if it exists, and want to log them in and move to set password page, but in django i cant use login(request, user), because request arent user generated through i have the user object, how can i achieve this functionality.

i am passing session key in webhook, so that i can gather the items in those cart and process and delete them after, and gets the user or create them in the webhook.

scenario

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpRequest, HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth import login, get_backends
User = get_user_model()


def home(request: HttpRequest) -> HttpResponse:
    return render(request, "learn/home.html")

@csrf_exempt
def webhook(request: HttpRequest):
    print(request)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        userid = request.POST.get("user_id")
        user = User.objects.get(id=userid)
        bks = get_backends()
        print(bks)
        login(request, user, backend=bks[0].__module__)        
        print(user)
        return HttpResponse("hello world")
```

```
import requests


ret = requests.post("http://localhost:8000/webhook/", data={"user_id": 1})

print(ret.content)
```